# in query taking id as $1 instead of 1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am facing problem please help me

```
 def messaging
  user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])

  @owner = user.owner
  authorize @owner

  if params[:renter_id].to_i == 0
    @renter = User.friendly.find(params[:renter_id]).renter
  else
    @renter = Renter.find(params[:renter_id])
  end     

   @messages = @owner.messages.where(renter_id: @renter.id).order(created_at: :desc)
   @last_property = Property.find(@messages.first.property_id)
   mark_read(@renter.id)
 end
```

here in the `@messages` i am getting query from backend like this

```
SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"  WHERE "messages"."owner_id" = $1 AND "messages"."renter_id" = 2  ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" DESC  [["owner_id", 1]]
```

Here `owner_id` is taking as $1 instead of 1 ,why?

Also please explain me about authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is numbered placeholders in PostgreSQL driver, It working correctly

Example:
The PostgreSQL driver wants to see numbered placeholders ($1, $2, ...) not question marks and you need to give your prepared statement a name:

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare('some_name',
>   "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = $1")